# My search terms are only printing our the last term in a list instead of the term found [Python 2.7.6]

Tags: python, list

I'm using the praw (reddit) api to search through comments in posts for a set of words, and return that word. Basically, my word list is well... just that, a list of words:

```
right = [ 'i', 'he', 'she', 'it', 'we', 'have', 'has']
```

This is inside of words.py, which i've imported. I've saved this into a variable by iterating through it:

```
for word in words.right:
    za = word
    print za
```

When i print za, it prints out each individual word in words.right like I want it to. It prints:

```
i
he
she
it
we
have
has
```

My program returns the comments that contain one of these search terms just fine like so:

```
for comment in flat_comment_generator:

    try:
        if za in comment.body.lower() and comment.id not in already_done:


            fob.write(comment.id + "\n")
            print comment.body
            print za
```

But when I use print za, it only prints the last term in za, not what it found in the program. For instance, it might return:

```
"Comment found = Yeah, I really like basketball" "Search term = has"
```

So everything works fine until I ask it to return that specific term.

Comment: "I've saved this into a variable by iterating through it" ... Can you please elaborate?  How does iterating through something save it into a variable?  with what you've shown there, after the loop, `za` will have the value of the last item in `words.right`.

Comment: I'll edit it for clarity after this comment, but (and bear with me, I'm new to python) shouldn't "for word in words.right" iterate through each word in it? When i use "print za" the first time, it prints each word individually.

Comment: Yes, individually.  So after the loop is done, `za` has the value of the last thing that was printed.  I'm still not sure that I actually understand the problem here ...

Comment: @mgilson: perhaps, OP thinks (mistakenly) that `za = word` works like `za.append(word)`

Comment: Okay, I'll try to be more clear, I didn't explain well. I see my error here, and it's a dumb: I'm trying to look for any of the terms listed in words.right, and for some reason, I thought storing it in variable za, and then seaching the comments for za would work. What I need to do is search comments for the terms in words.right and have it return the term that it found. I feel like I'm over-complicating it, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot see from your code how this search all words in comments as za will have only the last value of your word list. Yo can see all words as you print for each time you do the loop, but you won't get all if you do:

```
for word in words.right:
    za = word
print za
```

I guess what you're trying to do is something like:

```
for comment in flat_comment_generator:

    try:
        if comment.id not in already_done:
           terms = []
           # Search all the terms
           for word in words.right:
               if word in comment.body.lower():
                   terms.append(word)

           # If any term is in the comment
           if len(terms) != 0:
               fob.write(comment.id + "\n")
               print comment.body
               print terms
```

I hope it helps, otherwise just ask.

Comment: Thank you! My logic approaching this problem was just a mess. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: `len(terms) != 0` can be replaced with just `terms`

Comment: Well spotted Blender. I'm still fairly new in python,  less than a month, so I still tend to be a bit verbose. Thanks for the advice